# .classpath is not getting recreated after adding in .ignore (Anypoint Studio 7)

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm running into an issue that Anypoint Studio can't create the .classpath for my Mule application project after I have added it the .ignore (which include .settings, .classpath) file. If I also pull someone else's project from git, I get a completely different structure, because the classpath is not created. I've tried using buildpath and build resources but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how this can be solved. Thanks in advance.

.ignore file:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# Java defaults (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore) #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
*.class

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Eclipse-specific (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore) #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
*.pydevproject
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath
.project
.classpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# --------------- #
# Studio-specific #
# --------------- #
target/
.mule/**
.mule/**/*
.DS_Store
velocity.log
```

Output that I get when I clone, which is not working 
[image: 1]

My desire output (maven structure) 
[image: 2]

Comment: Seems like you are importing incorrectly. Are you importing like this? 
* Import > Project from Git > clone URI > .... > "Import as General Porject" * ?

Comment: `Anypoint studio Mulesoft 4` doesn't exists. Please share the version the version of Anypoint Studio. The version of Mule is not relevant since this is not an execution issue. MuleSoft is the company name, not of any of its products.

Comment: Please share any errors or warning from the error log.

Comment: @HarshankBansal, First I import the project into GIT tool in anypoint and than I import it. I also tried what you mentioned and I get the same result (no proper structure). I use the version 7.12.1.

Comment: The error I get when I try to run "Cannot run project 'virtual-mule-project-1'. The project mjay have classpath issue or the workspace may be corrupt.

Comment: The issue is with your .project file. please share the .project file. it should have following entries in the file  -

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your .project file. please share the .project file. it should have the following entries in the file  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>AppName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.mule.tooling.core.muleStudioBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.mule.tooling.core.muleStudioNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```